# Let user settle picking value from CupertinoPicker(onSelectedItemChanged ), after that it should send call to API

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am using CupertinoWidget for iOS users to scroll through List and check the price of a currency. But when scroll happens, **onSelectedItemChanged** sends callback to API for every value from the list. I read the document but unable to understand what to do. It pleasing if there is an example.

In document it's mentioned as [CupertinoPicker > onSelectedItemChanged property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker/onSelectedItemChanged.html)

> This can be called during scrolls and during ballistic flings. To get the value only when the scrolling settles, use a NotificationListener, listen for ScrollEndNotification and read its FixedExtentMetrics.

```
 NotificationListener cupertinoPickerList() {
    List<Text> textWidgetList = [];
    for (String curreny in currenciesList) {
      textWidgetList.add(
        Text(
          curreny,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },
      child: CupertinoPicker(
        itemExtent: 30,
        scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 19),
        onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
          selectedCurreny = currenciesList[selectedIndex];
          updateUI(selectedCurreny);
          print(selectedCurreny);
        },
        children: textWidgetList,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the `metrics` of the `scrollNotification` are of type `FixedExtentMetrics`. This type has the value itemIndex which you can use to determine which item is currently selected.

```dart
  return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
      if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification &&
      scrollNotification.metrics is FixedExtentMetrics) {
        (scrollNotification.metrics as FixedExtentMetrics).itemIndex; // Index of the list
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Juliantje15](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13031778/juliantje15)'s code, here is a full solution:

```dart
final widget = NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    if (notification.metrics is! FixedExtentMetrics) {
      return false;
    }

    final index = (notification.metrics as FixedExtentMetrics).itemIndex;

    // This would be your callback function. Could use items[index]
    // or something if that's more appropriate of course.
    onItemChanged(index);

    // False allows the event to bubble up further
    return false;
  },
  child: CupertinoPicker(
    itemExtent: 32,
    onSelectedItemChanged: null, // Attribute is marked required
    children: [Text('item1'), Text('item2'), Text('etc')], 
  ),
);
```

It seems quite sensible to want this, so I guess it's a bit strange that this isn't included as an (optional) default behavior. I guess you could turn the wrapper into a custom widget if it's needed more often.